# RSpec. Testing arguments of block call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I bumped with a problem of testing arguments of block calling in my rails project.

I've approximately this code (simplified):

```
DropboxApi.read_path do |batch|
    # some actions are here
end
```

Where batch is hash of data.

And i have an rspec spec which tests DropboxApi methods where i need to test some fields of 'batch'. I want to get something like this:

```
it { expect(batch).to respond_to(:data) }
it { expect(batch.data.count).to eq(6) }
```

I didn't find some ways to do it. Yield matchers are not helpful in that case, because they are checking only a block call and not it's arguments.

Could anybody help to implement what i want? I think i probably should change my approach for spec. But i don't know how yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually really straight forward.

```
it "responds to data" do
  DropboxApi.read_path do |batch|
    expect(batch).to respond_to(:data)
  end
end

it "has a count of 6" do 
  DropboxApi.read_path do |batch| 
    expect(batch.data.count).to eq(6)
  end
end
```

And if you really want it to look more terse, like your example you can do the following.

```
let(:batch) {
  DropboxApi.read_path do |batch|
    return batch
  end
 }

 it { expect(batch).to respond_to(:data) }
 it { expect(batch.data.count).to eq(6) }
```

Comment: It's really straightforward :) It's weird that i didn't try it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious from your question, but if what you need is to check what parameter is passed to the block when calling `DropboxApi.read_path`, you can simply call that API, and save the value passed to the block to be inspected:

```
let(:batch) {
  res = nil
  DropboxApi.read_path do |batch|
    res = batch
  end
  res
}

it { expect(batch).to respond_to(:data) }
it { expect(batch.data.count).to eq(6) }
```